# Cross Product in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I was looking at the index of "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler and I couldn't find the cross product mentioned at all while the dot product is mentioned in pretty much all the later chapters. Is the dot product actually the more important concept in linear algebra?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The cross-product is defined for vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, whereas the dot product is defined for vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n$

Comment: oh, thanks. Thats interesting

Comment: And I guess the generalized inner product is defined for all vector space. Is there no equivalent for the cross product that generalize it for different kinds of vector space?

Answer (score 3):

[Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_produc) is for $\mathbb{R}^3$. The general notion is called [exterior/wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). You will see this notion in  [multilinear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_algebra). Inner product, on the other hand, is a fundamental concept for inner product spaces. I would not say which one is "more important". It is just that you are learning different topics in algebra.